# Pandas DataFrame subtract values

Tags: pandas, dataframe, lambda

Im new to python

I have a data frame (df) which has the following structure:

| ID | rate | Sequential number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 150 | 1 |
| a | 150 | 1 |
| a | 50 | 2 |
| b | 250 | 1 |
| c | 25 | 1 |
| d | 25 | 1 |
| d | 40 | 2 |
| d | 25 | 3 |

The ID are customers, the value are monthly rates and Sequential number is a number that always increases by 1, if the customer changes the monthly rate

I want to do the following:
for every ID find the maximum value in the column *Sequential number*, take the associated value in the column rate, find the minimum value in  the column *Sequential number* and take associated value in the column rate and subtracting the rates.

At the end I want to have a additional column to my data frame with the difference of the rates. Maybe the loop could do the following:

```
for id in df() 
    find max() in column Sequential number  and get value in rates - 
     min () in column Sequential number and get value in rates
return difference
```

The new df_new should be this

| ID | rate | Sequential number | rate_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 150 | 1 | 0 |
| a | 150 | 1 | 0 |
| a | 50 | 2 | -100 |
| b | 250 | 1 | 0 |
| c | 25 | 1 | 0 |
| d | 25 | 1 | 0 |
| d | 40 | 2 | 0 |
| d | 30 | 3 | 5 |

If an ID has only one entry, the rate_diff should be 0

I tried already the lambda Function:

```
df['diff_rate'] = df.groupby('ID')['rate'].transform(lambda x : x-x.min())
```

but this returns

| ID | rate | Sequential number | rate_diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 150 | 1 | 100 |
| a | 150 | 1 | 100 |
| a | 50 | 2 | 0 |
| b | 250 | 1 | 0 |
| c | 25 | 1 | 0 |
| d | 25 | 1 | 0 |
| d | 40 | 2 | 15 |
| d | 30 | 3 | 10 |

Maybe someone of you have a small workaround for this! :-)

Comment: `df.groupby('ID')['value'].diff()`?

Comment: Should this be grouped by `id` or both `id` and `sequential number`? I'm having trouble getting your desired results.

Comment: For example: 40 - 25 is 15 for `d`. How are you getting 0?

Comment: it should only grouped by id.

Answer (score 0):

One approach with indexing:

```
g = df.groupby('ID')['Sequential number']
IMAX = g.idxmax()
IMIN = g.idxmin()
df['rate_diff'] = 0
df.loc[IMAX, 'rate_diff'] = (df.loc[IMAX, 'rate'].to_numpy()
                            -df.loc[IMIN, 'rate'].to_numpy()
                             )
```

Another with `groupby.transform`+`where`:

```
g = df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'Sequential number']).groupby('ID')

m = g['Sequential number'].idxmax()
df['rate_diff'] = (g['rate'].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[-1]-x.iloc[0])
                            .where(df.index.isin(m), 0)
                   )
```

output:

```
  ID  rate  Sequential number  rate_diff
0  a   150                  1          0
1  a   150                  1          0
2  a    50                  2       -100
3  b   250                  1          0
4  c    25                  1          0
5  d    25                  1          0
6  d    40                  2          0
7  d    30                  3          5
```